# How to correctly elevate privileges in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, sudo, visual-studio-mac

Using .NET Core 2.1.4 on High Sierra, I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace socketTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var udpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Udp);
            Console.WriteLine($"udpSock object is: {udpSock}");

            var tcpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Console.WriteLine($"tcpSock object is: {tcpSock}");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

From the terminal, I execute: `sudo dotnet socketTest`, which outputs:

```
udpSock object is: System.Net.Sockets.Socket
tcpSock object is: System.Net.Sockets.Socket
Press any key to exit
```

However, when I open Visual Studio for Mac with elevated privileges from the terminal (with `sudo ./Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio`), and attempt to run the program, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to connect to the specified connection id.
bash: /tmp/tmp339daafd.tmp: Permission denied
```

How do I correctly run this from inside Visual Studio for Mac?